# Win-X (Power User Menu) stops working after Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

Everything just doesn't open except for "run" and "desktop".

I can click them from `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX` just not from the menu. As many other people from other sites suggested to use ShellExView, I disabled every single shell extension I could (and made sure to refresh) and none will still open.

Not sure what else there is to do.

Edit: Used [Microsoft's Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and went under Explorer and disabled and reenabled everything, this fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP apparently solved it, edited their solution into their question, and vanished.